# Calculate after effects composition un-stretched time

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-scripting

How can I get or calculate the original current composition time of a time-remapped or stretched layer?
My composition has both stretched and non stretched layers and I want to display the current playback time (relative to the composition) as it would be if non of the layers were stretched.

Answer (score 0):

The source time of a layer is found with the expression

```
thisComp.layer("some layer").sourceTime()
```

More about it can be found by [reading the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-language-reference.html#layer_sub_objects_attributes_and_methods_expression_reference).